# Editing 20 listboxes with two variables

Tags: vb.net

So I have 20 listboxes (from 1 to 20) and I want to perform the same operation on them, here in this code you see `listbox1`:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    SelectedProfile3.SelectedIndex = 1
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 1

    While (ListBox1.SelectedItem.Length < SelectedProfile3.SelectedItem) And SelectedProfile3.SelectedIndex = 1

        ListBox1.Items(ListBox1.SelectedIndex) = ListBox1.SelectedItem + (" ")
    End While
    Button4.PerformClick()
End Sub
```

On `listbox2` things that will change are:

1. `SelectedProfile3.SelectedIndex = 2`
2. Use `listbox2` instead of `listbox1`

And so on for the rest of listboxes

Comment: I have a sinking feeling that Button4.Click calls this Sub again. Is this so?

Comment: Turn on Option Strict now and forever. This is done in Project Properties on the compile tab. After you have fixed the problems this will point out, fix the code in your question.

Comment: Firstly, why are you calling `Button4.PerformClick()` in the `Click` event handler of `Button4`?  Do you not see a problem with that?  As for the question, you should learn about `For` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Just set list-box names or either type code-block(separate-subject to call at the time of execution).

As I can see you are doing while loop with **integer and string** as you write
(ListBox1.SelectedItem.Length **(double data type)** < SelectedProfile3.SelectedItem **(string type)**)

It may reduce proper functionality or errors at runtime. **Although I understand you can type digits in that list only and then it will work for you.**

As you are using **while statement no need to call PerformClick()** again simply put you code in while loop and remove from outside.

However I still don't understand why you use

```
 ListBox1.Items(ListBox1.SelectedIndex) = ListBox1.SelectedItem + (" ")
```

But for editing 20 list-boxes simultaneously you should do :

```
      Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click    
         while (ListBox1.SelectedItem.Length < SelectedProfile3.SelectedItem) And SelectedProfile3.SelectedIndex = 1
              ListBox1.Items(ListBox1.SelectedIndex) = ListBox1.SelectedItem + (" ")
              SelectedProfile3.SelectedIndex = 1
              ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 1
          End While
      End Sub
```

**As you are comparing you can't use loop without specifing name of control, it can be done for items in each listbox.**

In code I have enter **ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 1** inside while statement then no need to perform click again.

If you want to work with 20 list-boxes( **not list-items as you write question on list-boxes**) at single time then you can use For loop or For each loop for list-box items but for different list names should be specify, Otherwise to change all similar controls in form like list-boxes use {For each listbox in me.controls}.
You don't need to perform this click again and again.

*Note : comparing controls without specifying their unique name is difficult as compiler will not understand what you compare and with what.*

Comment: hey thx for the repy
i use ListBox1.Items(ListBox1.SelectedIndex) = ListBox1.SelectedItem + (" ")    with a button perform click 
because i want to keep  adding  the (" ") to the end of the selected item till it reaches a specific length  the button perfromclick keeps doing this command till it reaches the length